# When values are pasted into a bigger range, the values should be repeated as needed to fill the range

Tags: javascript, array

I am currently working on a project, and I just wrote a piece of it that requires a lot of array manipulation.  Given a text input I want to expand it to fill the number of rows and columns I have.  I worked out a solution, but I am concerned that I am creating too many arrays in my solution.  I am looking for pointers on how I can make this code more efficient.  I always get really lost when trying to refactor things like this.

```
function fillIn(data,numRows,numCols) {
  // First, split the data by newlines and tabs into an array of arrays.
  var dataArr = data.split('\n').map(function(row) { return row.split('\t'); });

  function fillRows(pRows){
    return [].concat.apply([], new Array(Math.floor(numRows / pRows.length)).fill(pRows));
  }

  function fillCols(pRows) {
    for (var i = 0; i < pRows.length; i++) {
      pRows[i] = [].concat.apply([], new Array(Math.floor(numCols / pRows[i].length)).fill(pRows[i]));
    }
    return pRows;
  }

  function fillSelection(pRows) {
    if (numRows > pRows.length) {
      pRows = fillRows(pRows);
    }
    if (numCols > pRows[0].length) {
      pRows = fillCols(pRows);
    }
    return pRows;
  }

  dataArr = fillSelection(dataArr);

  return dataArr;
}

console.log(fillIn('foo',2,2)); //[['foo','foo'],['foo','foo']]
console.log(fillIn('foo\tbar',4,2)); //[['foo','bar'],['foo', 'bar'],['foo','bar'],['foo','bar']]
console.log(fillIn('foo\nbar',2,4)); // [['foo','foo','foo','foo'],['bar','bar','bar','bar']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ECMAScript 6

If you're able to use ECMAScript 6 then arrow functions could help clean up some of your code.

```
var dataArr = data.split('\n').map(row => row.split('\t'));
```

---

### Unit Testing

You're logging the results, but it would be extremely helpful for your refactoring process to create some test cases for your function.

```
function test(input, expected) {
  var result = fillIn(input.data, input.numRows, input.numCols);

  function matrixEquals(m1, m2) {
    if (m1.length !== m2.length) return false;

    for (var r = 0; r < m1.length; r++) {
      if (m1[r].length !== m2[r].length) return false;

      for (var c = 0; c < m1[r].length; c++) {
        if (m1[r][c] !== m2[r][c]) return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }

  if (!matrixEquals(expected, result)) {
    throw "Test Failed for: input=" + JSON.stringify(input) +
      ", result=" + JSON.stringify(result);
  }
}

test({
  data: "foo\tbar",
  numRows: 2,
  numCols: 2
}, [
  ["foo", "bar"],
  ["foo", "bar"]
]);

test({
  data: "foo\tbar\nfat\tcat",
  numRows: 4,
  numCols: 4
}, [
  ["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar"],
  ["fat", "cat", "fat", "cat"],
  ["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar"],
  ["fat", "cat", "fat", "cat"]
]);
```

If you write your test cases well, you'll be able to tell if you broke your function simply by running the test cases.

---

### Do you really even need to create all the arrays?

You could just extend the initial array directly:

```
function fillIn(data, numRows, numCols) {
  var matrix = data.split('\n').map(row => row.split('\t'));

  var missingRows = numRows - matrix.length;
  for (var r = 0; r < missingRows; r++) {
    matrix.push(matrix[r].slice());
  }

  var missingCols = numCols - matrix[0].length;
  for (var c = 0; c < missingCols; c++) {
    matrix.forEach(function(row) {
      row.push(row[c]);
    });
  }

  return matrix;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  You are right I should have included better test cases.  As a result of my poor testing, I think you missed one part of the problem.  Values not only have to expand into the new range they also have to fit. \n i.e. test({
  data: "foo\tbar",
  numRows: 3,
  numCols: 3
}, [
  ["foo", "bar"],
  ["foo", "bar"]
]);
I added a function that checks for that and now it works.
  function findBestFit(newLen,matrixLen) {
    var fit = newLen - matrixLen;
    while (fit % matrixLen !== 0) {
      fit -= 1;
    }
    return fit;
  }